# Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found, Getting this error when trying to log into MS account using WAM

Tags: authentication, xamarin, uwp, azure-ad-msal, xamarin.windows

I am trying to implement MSAL to a xamarin windows app. When im trying to use AcquireTokenInteractive it gives me this error.

" {"Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port
both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details"} "

CODE:
`app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
.WithBroker()
.Build();

System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

AcquireTokenInteractiveParameterBuilder interactiveRequest = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(GetScopes).WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();`

AND in Azure AD i have added the below redirecr Uri;
"ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/{sid}"

This worked for me when i was working on the feature branch and now when i have merged this into the master, it's not working.